# How to print map() object results stored in a variable multiple times?

Tags: python

Recently I was trying out something for ways to print a `map()` result, where I came across `*`

I tried out this:

```py
>>> def inc(x):
...     return x+1
...
>>> a = map(inc,[1,2,3,4,5])
>>> print(*a)
2 3 4 5 6
>>> print(*a)
```

Here with a function `inc()` I stored the map object result in `a`. On printing it using `print(*a)`,
I get the desired output. Running the command second time prints out nothing. Why?

I wondered that has anything happened to `a`, and tried this to check `type()` of `a`:

```py
>>> type(a)
<class 'map'>
```

But it seems to be all good. So why am I not able to print results using `print(*a)` command a second time?
Even when I tried to print using `[i for i in a]`, Its possible for the first time and not possible for the second, it gets me `[]`. What is the problem?

Comment: Save it to list or tuple: `list(map())`

Comment: I would have done that but wanted to explore problem behind this @OlvinRoght

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` object can be considered as an iterator over a some sequence of data. In a nutshell, the `map` object applies the function that you have specified, each time `next` is applied to it. It does not store the result.

So, with `*`, you effectively apply `next` onto `a` until `StopIteration`, and this means that you effectively apply the `inc` function at your data.

After that, you should re-initialize the `map`. Alternatively, you could use `tee`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee

If you want to store the result of `map` in a container, then you could initialize a `list` from the result of `map`, e.g.

```py
l = list(map(inc, [1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

This is equivalent of calling `*a`, but the result is passed to the `list` constructor and then assigned to the variable `l`.